# has Python 3 been widely adopted yet?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that when it launched, a lot of people didn't think it would be picked up very easily. I was wondering if thats changed at all. Do many of the major modules and libraries support Python 3 yet? Is it gaining acceptance or are people mostly sticking with 2.x?

Comment: I think you should be specific. Which library or module are you looking for?

Comment: For the record, I use Python 3 whenever I can, which is most of the time. I'm yet to run into lack of libraries for my pet projects - perhaps I'm lucky?

Comment: @delnan: You probably only have pet projects, and like to reimplement stuff, or use subpar libraries despite better libraries being available for py2. If you ran a serious cost/benefit analysis, you'd probably choose python2 instead, at least for now.

Comment: "subjective and argumentative" in this case means "Impossible to actually answer". Describe what you want to do, and people could tell you if the major libraries in that area have been ported. The real answer is "yes"... many major modules and libraries support Python 3, and "yes" it is gaining acceptance. You'll note that even with the answers, I still haven't provided any useful information.

Comment: @nosklo: That's a rather remarkable bit of presumption on your part. For my (commercial) projects Python3 is actually significantly better than py2, and our very serious cost/benefit analysis caused us to move several months ago. And on your second comment... I'm answering the only literal question in the original question, provably factually. The answer someone actually needs to know about this is more along the lines of "Will the (library) functionality I need for an XYZ project be available in py3?" Just because it's gaining acceptance doesn't mean it will overtake py2.

Comment: like delnan, i use python 3 whenever i can. unfortunately, i find libraries lacking python 3 (PIL, and many others) although library developers are catching up. but the worst part is OS support: python 3 is far from making it into debian stable, and this really prevents me form doing some useful stuff on linux... (my clients are all using debian)

Comment: @nosklo: Both assumptions are true but don't apply here as much as you imply. One of these projects is a (anything but trivial) XML editor with GUI - mainly driven by lxml and PyQt, two excellent libraries available for Python 3, and the standard libary (which is about equal for 2.x and 3.x) does most of the remaining work that one can expect to find a library for.

Comment: @delnan: Those libraries are also available for python2. So why use python3 then, when uou could just use python2 and have your program work on BOTH? I can't see how that wouldn't be better than using only python3.

Comment: @nosklo: Yes, about all that work on Python 3 work on 2.x as well. Of course. You questiom comes down to "why use Python 3 at all?" - the answer is, of course, the language. Believe it or not, but there are people who prefer not to work around the (thankfully rare, but still existent) annoyances and edges of Python 2 (killer for me, but not the only example: unicode not default).

Comment: @delnan: I'm not sure what you mean by "unicode not default". Do you mean unicode literals, as in `from __future__ import unicode_literals` ? If it will **kill** you (as in *killer* that you said this feature is for you) to type a small `u''` on your unicode literals (or use the above `__future__` import), then I'm really sorry, but I can't discuss that with you, really. It looks a lot like "cosmetic syntax change with no improvements at all" to me.

Comment: @nosklo: If you don't even know Python 3, don't discuss if one should use it. Yes, the differences are relatively small - it's not a wholly new language, of course not - but it's enough to make Python 3 a(n even) better language overall. As for unicode: In Python 2 you get `bytes` (called `str` in Python 2) unless you explicitly ask for unicode. For text, you usually want unicode, not bytes. This is what Python 3 does without being told so. Python 2 doesn't. You need to encode/decode manually.

Comment: @delnan: You seem to not know python 2 yourself. Python 2 behaves exactly the same with regard to unicode as python3. Only the literal strings in the code have changed, i.e., you don't have to put the small `u` at the beginning of strings anymore. The rest is only renames, i.e., "text mode" from `open()` in 3.x lies at `codecs.open` in 2.x.

Comment: @nosklo: you seem quite clueless about Python 3 yourself. Python 2 has lots of shortcomings wrt. unicode, including I/O, exception printout, filesystem paths support, etc.

Comment: @Antoine P.: Perhaps you don't know how to work around those "shortcomings", but I do - I have to write unicode-aware python 2 applications in my daily job. My point is that, while more convenient, python3 doesn't **add** stuff that you can't do with python2.

Comment: @nosklo: it's great that you "know how to work around", but it's still far nicer not having to work around everything. I'm sure you're not thinking of everything, by the way (such as the pain of using non-ASCII unicode strings as exception messages when such an exception is displayed by Python's default exception hook).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you [go to `python.org` and click on **Download**](http://python.org/download/), there's this message:

> *If you don't know which version to use, start with Python 2.7; more existing third party software is compatible with Python 2 than Python 3 right now.*

I think that's the case. Python 2 is still more ***useful***.

Example: you don't have [WSGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface) working on python3 yet.

You could always write code in python2, and then port it to python3 later if all libraries are already ported, by running `2to3`. The opposite is not true: If you write python3 code and later want to use a library only on python 2, you're out of luck :( I think that's why python.org recommends python2 **even for new projects**, by suggesting you start with python 2.7.

Using python3 also **doesn't buy you anything** right now - there are some small niceties, but ***losing full 3rd party support*** far **outweights** the tiny gains of the small syntax changes and module relocations.

Don't get me wrong -- I love python3 and all the new nice things it can do, it's beautiful and much closer to the way I think python should be.

The thing is that using it just doesn't pay back, yet. You need either more benefits or less downfalls to make it worth the trouble.

Comment: yeah but that message has been there since python 3 started. Figured it might just be something they never bothered removing

Comment: @Matt: No, I believe it is still valid, and couldn't be more truthful. In fact, python3 was released with python 2.6, so people must've had a look at that message at least once, to change it when 2.7 shipped.

Comment: Although true, don't let this advice alone prevent you from using Python 3. It does have many libraries - not all, but more than enough to be practical for many kinds of projects. If all libraries you'll ever need for a project have been ported to Python 3, there's no reason not to use it for that project - quite the contrary, it's simply a better language.

Comment: Actually, PEP 3333 just got passed. So, we have wsgi, but no implementation.

Comment: @delnan: Yeah, but using python2 in first place is better: You could always write it in python2, and then port it to python3 later if all libraries are already ported, by running `2to3`. The opposite is not true: If you write python3 code and later want to use a library only on python 2, you're out of luck :( That's why python.org recommends python2 **even for new projects**. Using python3 also **doesn't buy you anything** right now - there are some small niceties, but ***losing full 3rd party support*** far **outweights** the tiny gains of the small syntax changes and module relocations.

Comment: @nosklo: there is 3to2 tool similar to 2to3. But I agree that python2 is more practical now (and I think it'll be more practical at least for next couple of years).

Comment: -1 for "Using python3 also doesn't buy you anything right now". It improves Unicode handling, which is useful to everyone who cares about languages other than English (i.e. English-only speakers may tend to underestimate the value of this improvement).

Comment: @Craig McQueen: Improves unicode handling in *what* exactly? Nothing new was added, python2 includes __the same__ unicode type and tools that python3 does. Only the semantics changed, and not in a really groundbreaking useful way. The changes are minimal!

Comment: @Mike Korobov: Yeah, but 3to2 is not officially distributed, so that doesn't mean it's good or reliable. On the other hand 2to3 is recommended by python.org as a migration tool

Comment: Actually the most important thing re Unicode handling was what was taken away: implicit/automatic conversions between Unicode and byte strings. The automatic conversions in 2.x were bug-inducing, while 3.x's clean separation between Unicode and bytestrings aims to avoid such surprises. With 3.x, the effort of testing your software's Unicode handling should be reduced.

Comment: E.g. in 2.x, your program might appear to work, but actually only works because of implicit Unicode/bytestring conversions in some places--which you don't realise because you only tested it with ASCII test inputs. Then when a foreign language user puts in a string with non-Latin-1 characters, your program generates an exception.

Comment: @Craig McQueen: My native language is outside ascii, so I'm very used to doing all conversions explicity already. But If I was in the situation you describe, I'd probably use some warning-encoder like this http://twistedmatrix.com/~washort/ascii_with_complaints.py as default encoding. That would help me fix my code's implicit encodings while still allowing the stdlib and other modules to work.

Comment: @nosklo: That warning-encoder is a great idea. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Just FYI, this answer isn't up to date anymore. A lot more modules are compatible and the recommendation on the Download page is now `If you don't know which version to use, try Python 3.4. Some existing third-party software is not yet compatible with Python 3; if you need to use such software, you can download Python 2.7.x instead.`

Comment: Still valid answer as of now. I hope I will never will have to deal with Python3. I truly hope Python3 will be another Perl6

Answer (score 8):

The answer to all your questions are "Yes". :)

> Do many of the major modules and libraries support Python 3 yet?

Yes.

> Is it gaining acceptance

Yes.

> or are people mostly sticking with 2.x?

Yes.

Your question is a bit fuzzy, namely. If you are wondering if you should use Python 2 or Python 3, then the answer is "Use Python 2". There are many who uses Python 3, but they wouldn't ask the question. :-)

I'd expect that to change in 1-2 years, when the answer will be "well, it depends". And in around 3 years the answer will be "Are you using a library/framework that hasn't been ported?"